# PHP/Laravel: cURL error 56: SSL read: error:00000000:lib

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, curl, cpanel

I am getting this error on one function in my laravel application. yesterday everything worked fine.

> cURL error 56: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104 (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
>
> in CurlFactory.php line 187 at
>   CurlFactory::createRejection(object(EasyHandle), array('errno' =>
>   '56', 'error' => 'SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0),
>   errno 104', 'url' =>
>   'https://server7.phasehosting.io:2087/json-api/dumpzone?&domain=phasedev.be',
>   'content_type' => null, 'http_code' => '0', 'header_size' => '0',
>   'request_size' => '1174', 'filetime' => '-1', 'ssl_verify_result' =>
>   '0', 'redirect_count' => '0', 'total_time' => '2.30737',
>   'namelookup_time' => '0.004516', 'connect_time' => '0.02006',
>   'pretransfer_time' => '0.06986', 'size_upload' => '0', 'size_download'
>   => '0', 'speed_download' => '0', 'speed_upload' => '0', 'download_content_length' => '-1', 'upload_content_length' => '-1',
>   'starttransfer_time' => '0', 'redirect_time' => '0', 'redirect_url' =>
>   '', 'primary_ip' => '37.97.192.223', 'certinfo' => array(),
>   'primary_port' => '2087', 'local_ip' => '10.0.2.15', 'local_port' =>
>   '48858')) in CurlFactory.php line 150

When I specify the wrong parameters for the API call I get a server error response that I need to define the right parameters, when I specify the right parameters I get the Curl error.

When using postman to make the request I get a successfull response

Other API calls do work as intended. So I'm kind of confused right now. Where should I look?

This is the function that runs the query:

```
    protected function runQuery($action, $arguments)
    {
        $host = $this->getHost();
        $client = new Client(['base_uri' => $host]);
        try{
          $response = $client->post('/json-api/' . $action, [
              'headers' => $this->createHeader(),
              // 'body'    => $arguments[0],
              'verify' => false,
              'query' => $arguments,
              'timeout' => $this->getTimeout(),
              'connect_timeout' => $this->getConnectionTimeout()
          ]);

          return (string) $response->getBody();
        }
        catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e)
        {
          return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Guzzle are you using? Make sure it's not the outdated one. Guzzle bumped versions recently with BC problems.

Comment: I am running Guzzle 6.2.2, this issue really baffles me... There is one thing that has changed since yesterday, but this should not affect Guzzle. I downgraded Vagrant from 1.8.5 to 1.8.4, this was required to run DC/OS on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem and finally solved it.
Before you push anything into the header, make sure you `echo` it out. You can also use `dd($some_header_variable)` and eyeball every header variable that you have one at a time. **Pay special attention to variables that hold URL values.**
For my case, one of the header variables I had was not resolving to the correct value. Unfortunately guzzle, seemingly, does not do any error handling on headers.

For your case, first, try to `dd($host)` in the browser and assert that the intended value of `$host` is displayed.